# Is there a more generic way to call JS functions on an HTML element other than putting function calls against each element?

Tags: javascript

Currently I put a function call against each element like so:

```
<textarea id="comment" cols=70 rows=5 onblur="cleanWordClipboard(this)" />
```

Is there a more generic/central approach to adding:

```
onblur="cleanWordClipboard(this)"
```

to all TextArea elements, so

```
<textarea id="comment" cols=70 rows=5/>
```

stays as is. I am thinking something like CSS which has rules to apply behaviours to all elements of a certain type.

Thanks.

EDIT1

So far I am trying, at the bottom of my page, which is actually a master layout page that includes all dynamic pages (using ASP.NET MVC):

```
            <script language="JavaScript">
            // Thanks to Johnathan Hedley for this code.
            var swapCodes = new Array(8211, 8212, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8230); // dec codes from char at
            var swapStrings = new Array("--", "--", "'", "'", "\"", "\"", "*", "...");
            function cleanWordClipboard(input) {
                // debug for new codes
                // for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++)  alert("'" + input.charAt(i) + "': " + input.charCodeAt(i));    
                var output = input.value;
                for (i = 0; i < swapCodes.length; i++) {
                    var swapper = new RegExp("\\u" + swapCodes[i].toString(16), "g"); // hex codes
                    output = output.replace(swapper, swapStrings[i]);
                }
                //return output;
                input.value = output;
            }
            $('textarea').blur(cleanWordClipboard);
        </script>
```

EDIT2

```
       <textarea cols=10 rows=20 class="plaintextbox"></textarea>

       <script language="JavaScript">

            [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('plaintextbox'), function (element) {
                element.addEventListener('blur', cleanWordClipboard);
                // the element will be this in the cleanWordClipboard call
            });

            // Thanks to Johnathan Hedley for this code.
            var swapCodes = new Array(8211, 8212, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8230); // dec codes from char at
            var swapStrings = new Array("--", "--", "'", "'", "\"", "\"", "*", "...");
            function cleanWordClipboard(input) {
                // debug for new codes
                // for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++)  alert("'" + input.charAt(i) + "': " + input.charCodeAt(i));    
                var output = input.value;
                for (i = 0; i < swapCodes.length; i++) {
                    var swapper = new RegExp("\\u" + swapCodes[i].toString(16), "g"); // hex codes
                    output = output.replace(swapper, swapStrings[i]);
                }
                //return output;
                input.value = output;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: That's one way: [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in vanilla JavaScript:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('comment'), function(element){
    element.addEventListener('blur', cleanWordClipboard);
    // the element will be this in the cleanWordClipboard call
});
```

Note that I assume you use `class=comment` instead of `id=comment`, as only one element in a document can have a given id.

Comment: Using es6, you can do `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.comment')).forEach(...);`

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Which isn't shorter nor much clearer ;)

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually I was not planning on using the class or id attribute to link just the element name "TextArea". So how would you vanilla JS change to account for this?

Comment: @SamJolly change it to `document.querySelectorAll("textarea")`

Comment: Yes, but I'd really suggest to have something a little more future-proof than "textearea" as it would break as soon as you have a textarea not related to comments in your page.

Comment: Yes I agree with addressing via class name, and have tried this, however it does seems to work. No doubt there is an error in my code?? See EDIT2

Comment: @SamJolly Don't use `input` (the argument) in `cleanWordClipboard` but `this` (see comment in my answer).

Comment: @dystroy, thanks for reply, but I do not fully understand. How would I alter my EDIT2 code to work?

Comment: @dystroy, just testing, but looks promising....:) It all works, and this was the solution to the JQuery solution not working as well. So a big thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery and it will work for all `textarea` elements.

```
$('textarea').blur(function(){
     // code from cleanWordClipboard
});
```

Or simply

```
$('textarea').blur(cleanWordClipboard);
```

Comment: Added my full code to EDIT1, which for some reason is not working.

Comment: Did you include `Jquery` in your file?

Comment: Yes I did. It was to do with referencing "input" as opposed to "this" in the function which @dystroy advised me on. Thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way with jQuery would be `$("textarea").blur(cleanWordClipboard)`.